# What is the subtraction technique or derivative technique when dealing with infinite series?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

### Given:

Let $S=\sum_{i=1}^\infty(2i-1)\left(\frac23\right)^i$

I am to write out the first 5 terms of S. I need to use either the subtraction technique or derivative technique.

I have no clue what these techniques are and Google returns no results for these. Can somebody give me and example or point me in the right direction?

Comment: http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/Arithmetico-geometric_series  or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetico-geometric_sequence

Comment: Embarassing.. Guess, i need to learn to google. Thanks so much!

Comment: Huh? The first 5 terms of the sum are the 5 numbers you get by evaluating the summand at $i=1,2,3,4,5$, no?

Comment: Whoever assigned you the problem should have told you what those techniques are.  Perhaps look back in the previous few pages of the text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\displaystyle\sum_1^\infty(2i+1)\left(\frac23\right)^i=2\sum_1^\infty i\left(\frac23\right)^i+\sum_1^\infty\left(\frac23\right)^i$ . Now, we know that $\displaystyle\sum_0^n x^i=\frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1}$ which for $|x|<1$ and $n\to\infty$ becomes $\dfrac1{1-x}$ . In our case, $x=\dfrac23$ , so the second sum becomes $S=2$, since the term with exponent $0$, whose value is $1$, is missing. Now, notice that if we were to derive the second sum with regards to $x=\dfrac23$ , and then multiply it with $x=\dfrac23$ , we'd get the first sum. So, how much is $x\left(\dfrac1{1-x}-1\right)'_{x=\frac23}$ ? Double it, then add it to the value of $S=2$, and you're done! :-) By the way, these type of sums are called [polylogarithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm). See also [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Polylogarithm.html).

Comment: OP asked for "the first 5 terms of $S$". I'm not sure you have engaged with this question.